.Net MAUI Compilation problems, the app is aking me for some things that are done
At some point VS 2022 started to ask me to implemnt the project and it implemented
for some other reason it is not finding the icon image and it is there
it started to happen with no reason
can you help me please?
i am trying to finisih my app
i dont know how to solve it
can you give me some answers
Error (activo)  APT2067 failed processing manifest.
WiFixApp (net8.0-android)   C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets    214
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido    Detalles
Error (activo)  APT2260 resource mipmap/appicon (aka WiFixApp.WiFixApp:mipmap/appicon) not found.
This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file.    WiFixApp (net8.0-android)   C:\Users\oscar\source\repos\WiFixApp\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml

Please explain your question clearly. Did you mean the app icon missed when you run it? Could you please show the details?

Try to open project folder and deleted bin and obj folder, then clean and build the solution?

If you're still having issues, can you share the contents of the manifest at \Users\oscar\source\repos\WiFixApp\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml

This error has cropped up for me a few time too!
For the android manifest:
I had random error intermittantly. They stopped when I created a copy of the AndroidManifest.xml file in the root of the project. It won't ever get used by the app, but has stopped related errors.
Afterwards, clear your built project by deleting bin & obj folders.
Close visual studio > Delete bin and obj folders > Reopen and rebuild your project.
For the mipmap/appicon:
The above will likely fix that as welll. I've never needed to do more that delete the bin and obj folders and rebuild to get rid of that error. These are auto generated as part of the build, and you should only need to edit the csproj icon references to update the icons in most instance.
